# Using Google Maps API with custom tiles

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-maps

So, basic gist is, I have my own tiles of not the real world I'd like to display with the Google Maps viewer. I've found examples of how to split an existing single image into tiles for use with it, but nothing that deals with setting up your own tiler.

I have map data such as this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44766482/superimage/index.html
Which right now is just a bunch of 1600x1600 images in an html table. This naive method works, but I'd like to switch to the more robust google api for better zooming and smarter streaming of the image data.

I've been unable to find a good example of how to generate your own tiles for the zoom levels and bring it together with some html/js.

If you want some more information for the goal process;
I have a python script that can output any size tiles of the map, at any zoom level. I'd like to bundle those together into a google maps api website. But in my own efforts I have not found a good example or documentation of how to do that. For one, I can only find examples of how the zoom levels work for the real world map, but not for a custom one.

Edit:

Got most things working as I want them, but I'm still confused regarding the "center" that can be set, as it's in lat and lng, which don't apply. I'd also like to set boundaries as currently it tries to load .png files outside of the maps range.

My current progress:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44766482/googlemapspreview/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, each zoom level is the 4 lower zoom tiles combined. A Projection function can be skipped to get orthogonal mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the google maps imageMapTypes:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes

Comment: I've seen that before, but I'm unsure of how to make use of that information in so many regards. For example, I have no idea how radius applies, as my map is a flat game world. I don't see where to put total world size, for example.

Comment: The basic premise when using a real-world map application like google maps or openlayers is that the tiles are a projection from a sphere to a flat surface. If you want to go for a flat world, then maybe try a huge radius so your part of the map will be as flat as possible?

Comment: I found out that it's possible to omit a projection function entirely which allows orthogonal, which opened the door to making it mostly work as I wish. The radius is then nonexistant.

Comment: Great find! Good luck with your project! :)